# Exclude a string from a word that's a variable with regex using lineinfile ansible module?

Tags: regex, ansible

I have an ansible playbook that uses `lineinfile` module.

It uses a variable `{{ inventory_hostname }}` for the `line:` part of the task

All the hosts in the inventory have a different name but each hostname's name ends with this `.super.vms` (don't ask why, it just has to be like this) so it looks something like this:

```
[webservers]
server1.super.vms
server2.super.vms
database1.super.vms

...
```

Now I want to add to `line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'` something so it appends the line without `.super.vms` so the file looks something like this:

```
server1
server2
database1

...
```

Or maybe create another variabale that lineinfile will use.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the `inventory_hostname_short` variable which excludes the last part for some reason.

Comment: you can also use "{{ inventory_hostname.split('.')[0] }}"